# Buckling of a timber column

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, everyday-life, stress-strain

I am wondering how the "buckling number" of a timber column is altered by having a vertical element attached to it. Blue line is a roof, green a concrete wall and black is the timber column and the beam.

I am basically asking what happens to "K" as described here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckling#Columns

or how the effective length of the collumn is altered in the "buckling equation".

[image]

Comment: This question might belong to [Engineering.SE]

Comment: @JohnAlexiou indeed, i didnt get any repsonse there however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beam creates a pin constraint where it connects to the column. Therefore take the top section which is longer and apply $K=0.699$ which corresponds to a fixed-pinned column.

[image: fig1]

with

$$P_{\rm cr} = \frac{\pi^2 E I}{ (K L_{23})^2 } $$

This works even though the connection to the beam is a fixed connection because the beam can deflect easier than it can expand or contract.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense, I myself wasnt sure it was an approprite way to do the calculations, theoretically speaking.

Comment: I think this hand calculation is going to be sufficiently close to the exact solution which would require FEA software to do.

Answer (score 3):

This is a *constrained column*.  the constraint member separates the column into two shorter columns. An *estimate* of the buckling load for failure can be had by solving for the buckling failure point of the *longer* of the two sub-columns.

Comment: Except the beam may make the column more unstable if it imparts a moment to do.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou what circumstances causes the latter to occur?

Comment: @Nocturnal - if you take a column and load it less than the critical load, and then apply a moment on the middle of it, it will buckle. If the beam above were pinned then it would indeed make the effective column length smaller, as it would constrain any movement. But the fixed joint between the parts complicates things.

Comment: @Nocturnal - what end conditions would you consider for the top section of the column? I guess that is the crux of your question.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou it is fixed